# Count unique users in last 60 mins per page with Redis HyperLogLog

Tags: algorithm, redis, hyperloglog

I’m designing an algorithm to count unique users on a set of pages, based on a 60min sliding scale

So it needs to find unique IPs (or tokens) that have hit a particular page and total up those hits within the last 60 mins

I need this to be very fast at scale (mainly to write but reading is a bonus). We could have 10,000s of users per page multiplied by 1000s of pages.

My research is pointing me to using Redis with HyperLogLog

I’m new to Redis coming from a Memcache background. Could anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

One way of doing this would be to keep an HLL key for each page/set of pages with a minute resolution. For example, if we're tracking 'index.html' and the current timestamp is 0, a visitor with the ID 'abc' can be tracked by:

```
PFADD index.html:0 abc
```

Once the minute had passed - i.e. timestamp 1 for simplicity - a visitor such as 'def' will be added to the next key:

```
PFADD index.html:1 def
```

And so forth. To count the number of unique visitors from the last 60 minutes, assuming the current timestamp 100, you'll need to call the `PFCOUNT` command and provide it with the names of all of these 60 keys, e.g.:

```
PFCOUNT index.html:100 index.html:99 ... index.html:41
```

Note: if you want "old" counts to be evicted, call [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire) after each call to `PFADD`.

Comment: I was thinking similar to this first via using `HLL` but I thought multiple `PFCOUNT`s won't eliminate duplicates on multiple `HLL`, i was wrong (checked the doc again). Great answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't get time intervals in a single `HyperLogLog` key.

Sorted set could be an option;

- You add your users to the sorted set as their entrance date as score and their user id as value with `ZADD`.
- You can use `ZCOUNT` to get total number of unique users in that time interval. I used small numbers for timestamps for example.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD activeusers:page:1 1 a1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD activeusers:page:1 1 a2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD activeusers:page:1 3 a5
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD activeusers:page:1 116 a7
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZCOUNT activeusers:page:1 60 inf
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE activeusers:page:1 60 inf
1) "a7"
```

When you are using `ZCOUNT`, you will define `MIN` as (current time - (60*60)) and `MAX` as `inf`, so it will take between (now - 3600 seconds) and (now).

One of the drawbacks for this one is, you need to remove old data from these sets manually via using `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREMRANGEBYSCORE activeusers:page:1 -inf 59
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE activeusers:page:1 -inf inf
1) "a7"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE activeusers:page:1 -inf inf WITHSCORES
1) "a7"
2) "116"
```